# How to check whether a u64 number larger than 2 ^ 54 is divisible by f64 with the minimal precision loss?

Tags: rust, floating-point, precision

For a `u64` number less than 2 ^ 54 it can be done without much of precision loss by casting to `f64`:

```rust
((6 as f64) % 1.5) < f64::EPSILON
```

For larger numbers, there will be a significant precision loss:

```rust
1u64 << 63           // 9223372036854775808
(1u64 << 63) as f64  // 9223372036854776000
```

and divisibility will be checked for a different number.

**Context**: JSONSchema's `multipleOf` keyword implementation

**Question**: What is the most efficient way to check divisibility for `u64` / `i64` numbers that do not fit the `f64` mantissa size (`f64::MANTISSA_DIGITS` which is 53)?

Comment: The question suggests you're treating the `f64` as infinitely precise, am I right?

Comment: Oh, I will correct the question, I meant - with the minimal precision loss

Comment: This is a questionable thing to do in the first place. I don't think your example implementation for the case that the integer can be represented exactly is what you want. Even if you represent the quotient `q` of to integers `a` and `b`  that are exactly representable as `f64` as exactly as possible, `a % q` might be much bigger than the epsilon of the floating-point type, for various reasons. It's difficult to get this right even in that case.

Comment: I took a look at https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#multiples, and in my opinion the `multipleOf` keyword is ill-defined. Is there any more precise definition what exactly it is supposed to mean?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Aha, so it doesn't work even for smaller cases, right? Is there a way to avoid casting completely then? Or how to minimize precision loss there?

Comment: There is another definition https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-02#section-6.2.1 but I am not sure if it makes things more clear

Comment: The best test for the case that the integers are exactly representable I can come up with is to check that `a / round(a / q)` is "close enough" to `q`, where "close enough" may even mean exactly equal, depending on what you want.

Comment: The specification kind of clears things up: "The JSON specification allows numbers with arbitrary precision, and
   JSON Schema does not add any such bounds.  This means that numeric
   instances processed by JSON Schema can be arbitrarily large and/or
   have an arbitrarily long decimal part, regardless of the ability of
   the underlying programming language to deal with such data."

Comment: So rounding and restricting to `u64` and `f64` are non-conforming in any case. You'd need to treat all numbers in the serialized JSON as exact and perform arbitrary-precision arithmetic on them, without any rounding or epsilon.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the input is coming from `serde_json::Value`, which as you said is not conforming anyway, but currently, I have this restriction :( Probably working with arbitrary precision numbers in `serde_json` worth another question

Comment: The problem I anticipate, and the reason I asked about the float being infinitely precise, is that 9223372036854775808 is not divisible by *exactly* 1.5, but it *is* divisible by 1.500000000000000000081315163, which is in the interval of real numbers that round to 1.5 when represented as `f64`. So if the `1.5f64` comes from a calculation of less than infinite precision, you've already lost the information you need to determine "divisibility".

Comment: One way to look at this is: `serde_json` has already trashed the precision you "needed" to give an exact answer, so you might as well just do `((n as f64) % p) / p < f64::EPSILON` (note I added `/ p` -- epsilon is dimensionless, so it doesn't make sense to compare it to something on the order of `p`). It won't be any more wrong than whatever else you would have done and it ought to still work when both numbers can be represented as exact `f64`s. But you'll still probably get "weird" results with some numbers that can't be exactly represented as `f64`, such as 0.3.

Comment: The particular example you choose to demonstrate precision loss doesn't actually involve any change of value. `(1u64 << 63) as f64` will have value exactly `9223372036854775808.0`. The _apparent_ value of `9223372036854776000` is an artifact of the way that Rust *prints* floating-point numbers by default, and doesn't reflect what's actually stored. (There are other examples where conversion to `f64` _will_ change the value, but this isn't one of them.)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution given that `u` is some integer and `x` is a finite non-zero IEEE-754 binary64 number with which we do IEEE-754 arithmetic. `x` is presumed to represent one specific number, as specified by IEEE-754, and prior rounding errors occurring while obtaining `x` are not considered. This answer speaks to the mathematics involved, not to the Rust semantics, as I am unfamiliar with Rust.

First, find the representation of `x` = `F` • 2<sup>`E`</sup>, where `F` is an odd integer and `E` is an integer. A simple method for this is:

- Set `F` to `x` and `E` to 0.
- While `F` is not an integer, multiply `F` by two and subtract one from `E`.
- While `F` is even, divide `F` by two and add one to `E`.

All of the above operations can be performed in IEEE-754 arithmetic with no rounding errors. If Rust offers a method to separate the significand and exponent of a floating-point number, akin to C’s `frexp` function, then incorporating it into the above can improve efficiency.

Now consider whether `u` is a multiple of `x` = `F` • 2<sup>`E`</sup>. By definition, it is if and only if there is an integer `k` such that `u` = `k` • `F` • 2<sup>`E`</sup>. We will see this is so if and only if `u` is a multiple of `F` and is a multiple of 2<sup>`E`</sup>, and each of these can be tested.

If 2<sup>`E`</sup> is an integer (`E` is non-negative) and such a `k` exists, then `u` is a multiple of `F` and is a multiple of 2<sup>`E`</sup>. Conversely, if `u` is not a multiple of `F` or is not a multiple of 2<sup>`E`</sup>, then no such `k` exists (by way of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic).

`F` is necessarily within bounds of the requested integer format (it is at most 53 bits), and we assume `F` can be converted to that format. Then divisibility of `u` by `F` can be tested. If 2<sup>`E`</sup> exceeds the maximum value of the integer format in which `u` is represented, then `u` is not a multiple of 2<sup>`E`</sup>. Otherwise, 2<sup>`E`</sup> can be converted to the format, and the divisibility of `u` by 2<sup>`E`</sup> can be tested.

If 2<sup>`E`</sup> is not an integer (`E` is negative), then, if the required `k` exists (so `u` is a multiple of `F`), it is a multiple of 2<sup>−`E`</sup>. Conversely, if `k` is not a multiple of 2<sup>−`E`</sup>, then `k` • `F` • 2<sup>`E`</sup> is not an integer, so it cannot equal `u`. Thus `u` is a multiple of `x` if and only if `u` is a multiple of `F`.